# JSONRPC method should be specified for params: "undefined" while batching the requests in web3 js

Tags: web3js, ether, contract-invocation, batch

I am able to get the balance for an ERC20 tokens in a loop, but when I try to use BatchRequest I get the following error **JSONRPC method should be specified for params: "undefined"**

**Below code is throwing an error:**

```
async function getBalanceInBatch(address) {
  const batch = new web3.BatchRequest();
  const contractData = balanceHex + address.substring(2);

  for (let token of tokens) {
    const params = { to: token.address, data: contractData, from: address };
    batch.add(web3.eth.call(params), callBack)
  }

  batch.execute()
}
```

`balanceOf` method name is mentioned in `balanceHex` which is 
`const balanceHex = "0x70a08231000000000000000000000000";`

**Working code without batch request:**

```
const contractData = balanceHex + address.substring(2);
const params = { to: contractAddress, data: contractData };
const result = await web3.eth.call(params);
```

Is anything I am missing, any help will be appreciated.

*Callback:*

```
function callBack(result) {
  console.warn("callback:", result)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `add()` method in `BatchRequest` accepts a request object:

```
batch.add(web3.eth.call.request(param, callBack))
```

Notice the `.request` that follows `.call`

**Final answer:**

```
function getBalanceInBatch(address) {
      const batch = new web3.BatchRequest();
      const contractData = balanceHex + address.substring(2);

      for (let token of tokens) { // tokens is list of erc20 tokens
        const params = { to: token.address, data: contractData, from: address };
        batch.add(web3.eth.call.request(params, callBack));
      }

      batch.execute()
    }

    function callBack(err, result) {
      const totalTokens = web3.utils.toBN(result).toString();
      const balance = web3.utils.fromWei(totalTokens, "ether");
      console.warn("balance", balance);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It fix the error but callback is not being called. I have updated the answer with call back function as well.

Comment: Changed my answer. The callBack should be passed as the second parameter to request() not to add(). Also the callBack function should accept 2 parameters: `function callBack(err, data)`

Comment: Yeah that worked, the only issue now result is always null, how can I get a balance for an erc20 tokens.

Comment: It works for me. Do you use the 1st or 2nd argument in the callback?

Comment: Yup, it worked for me as well now:) thanks a lot of the help.